# Proving $f=0$ a.e.

Tags: real-analysis

$f\in L_{loc}^{1}(\Omega)$(The locally integrable function). If $\forall \varphi\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ we have $$\int_{\Omega} f(x)\varphi(x)dx=0$$
Show that $f=0$ a.e.

I know how to prove it in some intervals such as $(0,1)$ by taking $\cos{n\pi x}$ and $\sin{n\pi x}$ and using the uniqueness of the Fourier coefficient. However, I don't know how to prove in the $\Omega$, and the $C_{0}^{\infty}$ is somehow strange in proving the statement. Any hints or solutions are welcomed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have sequence $ \phi_n \in C^\infty_c(\Omega) $ such that $ \phi_n \rightarrow \chi_{B(x,r)} $ locally uniformly. For sufficiently large $n$ if all $\phi_n $ are supported inside $K$ then you have the estimate for any $\epsilon >0 $
$$ |\int_\Omega (f\phi_n - f\chi_{B(x,r)})dx | \leq \int_\Omega |f||\phi_n - \chi_{B(x,r)}|dx \leq \epsilon\|f\|_{L^1(K\cap B(x,r))} $$
But as $\int_\Omega f\phi_n dx = 0 $ hence $\int_\Omega f\chi_{B(x,r)} dx = 0 $, thus $ f = 0 $ a.e from lebesgue differentiation theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: consider smooth, compactly supported 'bump' functions that converge to a Dirac delta.

Comment: That's a good idea, but how to show the convergence of this limit? And how to show that this convergence to zero is a.e. but not everywhere? Thanks for your help.